# Writing an element to a list inside another file

Tags: python, list, append

I have 2 .py files. Let's name them foo.py and list.py

list.py is not having any code but just a list which looks like this: `allowed = ['a', 'b', 'c']`
This is all the list.py contains...

Now, the foo.py has a code which basically uses the list inside the list.py to only allow certain inputs (which should be in the list, else:    pass)

I added a code to be able to add elements to the list from inside the program, but i'm unable to do so. I have tried to use the append() function. This brings no change to the list...

Please help me edit and write changes to the list inside list.py by providing the right code to so.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50100019/edit) and include your code? Really, we need a [mcve]. It's impossible otherwise to guess your logic.

Comment: It sounds like `list.py` should actually be a data structure like `pickle` or `json` but you need to show your actual code

Comment: Can you replace the .py file with a json or yaml file? Or you want to keep the .py

Comment: And you really, really, should not call a module `list.py` if you plan to import it into another Python program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is likely happening is you are sending a copy of the list, when your program is running - and then appending to that list - without impacting the initial list in list.py

I would look at making sure that when you instantiate the original list in list.py, you aren't doing so in such a way that means each time that code block is called, the list is defined again as you call that code block or function again.

If you are trying to use a program in foo.py to explicitly edit the list.py file, you are probably as well off to simply use python's [pickle module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html), which saves the state of python objects to file, and you would then be able to load them as normal later, for example:

```
try:
    with open(list, 'r') as file:
        yourlist = pickle.load(file)
except(FileNotFoundError):
   yourlist = ['someDefaultValue','anotherDefaultValue']

# Your code block, doing whatever you're doing

with open(list, 'w') as file:
    pickle.dump(yourlist, file)
```

Without knowing more about what you're looking at or exactly what you're trying to do - it's hard to give a better answer!